# ksoap2 NullPointerException error in android

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, ksoap2

I am having a problem using ksoap2 in android.

I used ksoap to communicate with the web service, but it gave me the following error. The code and exception log cat are below. It gives me that exception on the first line of the try block in my code.Could you help me please.

Activity Class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public final static String URL = "http://10.0.2.2:8081/Service/services/SqlService.SqlServiceHttpSoap11Endpoint/";
    public static final String NAMESPACE = "http://services.com";
    public static final String SOAP_ACTION= "http://services.com/locationData";
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "locationData";

    String str = null;
    TextView t;
    String longitude;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            }
        t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);



        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        request.addProperty("message","Hello");

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet=true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        try {
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        SoapPrimitive result;
        try {
            result = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
            String strRes = result.toString();
            String resultArr[] = strRes.split("&");
            longitude = resultArr[0];
            t.setText(resultArr[0]);
        } catch (SoapFault e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
    public void sendLocation(View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MappingActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("longitude",longitude);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

logcat:

```
> 06-16 09:18:56.590: D/dalvikvm(1293): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 54K, 5% free
> 2894K/3028K, paused 33ms, total 35ms 06-16 09:18:56.600:
> I/dalvikvm-heap(1293): Grow heap (frag case) to 6.217MB for
> 3480056-byte allocation 06-16 09:18:56.640: D/dalvikvm(1293):
> GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 3% free 6290K/6428K, paused 39ms, total 39ms
> 06-16 09:18:57.000: W/System.err(1293):
> org.ksoap2.transport.HttpResponseException: HTTP request failed, HTTP
> status: 404 06-16 09:18:57.000: W/System.err(1293):   at
> org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:237)
> 06-16 09:18:57.000: W/System.err(1293):   at
> org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:118)
> 06-16 09:18:57.000: W/System.err(1293):   at
> org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:113)
> 06-16 09:18:57.000: W/System.err(1293):   at
> com.example.abc.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:53) 06-16
> 09:18:57.000: W/System.err(1293):     at
> android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 06-16
> 09:18:57.010: W/System.err(1293):     at
> android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
> 06-16 09:18:57.010: W/System.err(1293):   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
> 06-16 09:18:57.010: W/System.err(1293):   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
> 06-16 09:18:57.010: W/System.err(1293):   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 06-16
> 09:18:57.010: W/System.err(1293):     at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
> 06-16 09:18:57.010: W/System.err(1293):   at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 06-16
> 09:18:57.010: W/System.err(1293):     at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 06-16 09:18:57.010:
> W/System.err(1293):   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 06-16
> 09:18:57.010: W/System.err(1293):     at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 06-16
> 09:18:57.010: W/System.err(1293):     at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 06-16 09:18:57.010:
> W/System.err(1293):   at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
> 06-16 09:18:57.010: W/System.err(1293):   at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 06-16
> 09:18:57.010: W/System.err(1293):     at
> dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 06-16 09:18:57.010:
> D/AndroidRuntime(1293): Shutting down VM 06-16 09:18:57.010:
> W/dalvikvm(1293): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception
> (group=0xb3a59ba8) 06-16 09:18:57.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1293): FATAL
> EXCEPTION: main 06-16 09:18:57.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1293): Process:
> com.example.abc, PID: 1293 06-16 09:18:57.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1293):
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
> ComponentInfo{com.example.abc/com.example.abc.MainActivity}:
> java.lang.NullPointerException 06-16 09:18:57.030:
> E/AndroidRuntime(1293):   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
> 06-16 09:18:57.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1293):   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
> 06-16 09:18:57.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1293):   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 06-16
> 09:18:57.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
> 06-16 09:18:57.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1293):   at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 06-16
> 09:18:57.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 06-16 09:18:57.030:
> E/AndroidRuntime(1293):   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 06-16
> 09:18:57.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 06-16
> 09:18:57.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 06-16 09:18:57.030:
> E/AndroidRuntime(1293):   at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
> 06-16 09:18:57.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1293):   at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 06-16
> 09:18:57.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at
> dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 06-16 09:18:57.030:
> E/AndroidRuntime(1293): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
> 06-16 09:18:57.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1293):   at
> org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.getResponse(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:534)
> 06-16 09:18:57.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1293):   at
> com.example.abc.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:67) 06-16
> 09:18:57.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at
> android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 06-16
> 09:18:57.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at
> android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
> 06-16 09:18:57.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1293):   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
> 06-16 09:18:57.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1293):   ... 11 more 06-16
> 09:23:57.430: I/Process(1293): Sending signal. PID: 1293 SIG: 9
```

[image]

Comment: please update with full logcat.

Comment: `envelope` or something in it's `onResponse()` is null... ?

Comment: what is your line 53 and 67?

Comment: I  added from 50 line screenshot.

Comment: You are getting a 404 error response, so somewhere you've not initialized a variable that you later used to start the next activity

Comment: Just debug the code and find out for yourself what is null...